# Двумерный массив со случайными числами

Tags: python, массивы

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему у меня точно такой же код работает по-другому? У автора приложения (1 фото) была допущена ошибка или у меня?

Скриншот приложения
[image: Скриншот приложения]

*А это мой код:*

[image: А это мой код:]

Также он в виде текса:

```
import random

def printLst(lst):
    for i in range (len(lst)):
        for j in range (len(lst[i])):
            print (f" {i}{j} ", end='')
        print()

n = 5
m = 9
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(m):
        a[i].append(random.randint(10, 99))

printLst(a)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код в виде текста а не картинке. Так его легче читать, копировать или искать.

Comment: Извиняюсь, учту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас:

```
print (f" {i}{j} ", end='') 
          ^^^^^^
```

А нужно:

```
print (f" {lst[i][j]} ", end='')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Вы печатаете "координаты" нужного элемента в списке списков, а нужно печатать сам элемент.